# Difference between String X, Y; and String X, String Y;

Tags: java, local-variables

As far as memory, is there any difference between creating a local variable using these two options below:

Option 1)

`private String A, B;`

Option 2)

`private String A; 
 private String B;`

Comment: It's a matter of preference, but you (and other people you are working with) should be consistent with the option you choose throughout your code base. Personally, I find option 2 preferable. It's harder to miss that there is a second variable being declared there. The variable names should start with a lowercase letter according to the Java code conventions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No difference...

```
public class DiffFirst {
    private String A, B;
}
```

vs

```
public class DiffSecond {
    private String A;
    private String B;
}
```

I execute:

```
javac DiffFirst.java
javac DiffSecond.java
```

and then:

```
javap -c DiffFirst.class
javap -c DiffSecond.class
```

Outputs:

```
Compiled from "DiffFirst.java"
public class DiffFirst {
  public DiffFirst();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}

Compiled from "DiffSecond.java"
public class DiffSecond {
  public DiffSecond();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

I would use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) and call those variables a and b.

Comment: I'm actually using CamelCases in my code base, I used A and B just for the sake of the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference except for human readability.

Comment: Can you please go ahead and cite any official doc source?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference , In my view the first option best

Comment: Why do you think the first option is better?

Answer (score 0):

string allocate at least 8 bits in memory for a variable with both ways